# How to parse value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**Sample string:**

> (13.910074099911057%2C+100.37796020507812)%2C(13.840746785080066%2C+100.27908325195312)%2C(13.712703652698178%2C+100.33126831054688)%2C(13.7620619168356%2C+100.50979614257812)

**Correct format:**

> 13.910074099911057, 100.37796020507812 13.840746785080066, 100.27908325195312 13.712703652698178, 100.33126831054688 13.7620619168356, 100.50979614257812

**Sample code:**

```js
var locate = window.location
document.GetPerimeter.Perimeter.value = locate

var text = document.GetPerimeter.Perimeter.value

function CopyPerimeter(str) {
    theleft = str.indexOf("=") + 1;
    theright = str.lastIndexOf("&");             

    return (str.substring(theleft, theright));
}

var ShowPerimeter = CopyPerimeter(text)
document.GetPerimeter.Perimeter.value = ShowPerimeter


function decode() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('Perimeter');
    var encoded = obj.value;
    obj.value = decodeURIComponent(encoded.replace(/\+/g, ""));
}
decode();
```

Comment: Ahh... so what's the question?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: wat kind of encoding is this? using decode() you can achieve something but not completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the script which parses your JAVASCRIPT String to the desired one:

```
var str = "(13.910074099911057%2C+100.37796020507812)%2C(13.840746785080066%2C+100.27908325195312)%2C(13.712703652698178%2C+100.33126831054688)%2C(13.7620619168356%2C+100.50979614257812)";
var strParsed = "";
var percentCame = 0;
for (var i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if( (str[i]!="(") && (str[i]!=")") ){
        if( (str[i]=="%") ){
            percentCame = 1;
        }
        if(percentCame==1){
            i += 4;
            strParsed = strParsed + "," + str[i];
            percentCame = 0;
        }
        else{
            strParsed = strParsed + str[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions to parse text in Javascript. Just use the `myString.match('myRegEx')` function and it will return an array with parsed values. Mind that the values are still in text format so they need to be cast into floats if you want to use them as such.

This regular expression might do the trick: `/[-+]?\d+\.?\d*[^)C%]/g`

If you need to modify the regular expressions to match other values, try using a online helper as the ones below:

http://www.regexr.com/

https://regex101.com/#javascript

I hope I understood your question correct.